# CSS width and height added to pseudo elements after transition

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue with some width and height being added to ":before" and ":after" on some Bootstrap 3 elements after I make a CSS transition (AngularJS ng-animate method).

It's an approach with AngularJS route change, an animation that I've seen online, to move the View with a slide.

[Here's a fiddle to see what is happening.](http://jsfiddle.net/XTWzC/31/)

In the first screen below, you can see on the ":before" there is a 1px width and no height.

But after I make the following transition:

```
.slide-left.ng-enter,.slide-left.ng-leave,
.slide-right.ng-enter,
.slide-right.ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: inherit;
  -ms-transition: 120s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 120s ease-in-out;
  transition:  120s ease-in-out;
}


.slide-left.ng-enter {
  z-index: 101;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.slide-left.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide-left.ng-leave {
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide-left.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

... then I get the 2nd image problem. Something is adding a 2px to the width and 1px to the height. You can see the effect this is having on the "< Back" button.

It's using an ng-class/ng-animate transition on the ng-view to move the angular route/template when I click a link in the page

Would anyone have any ideas where this is coming from?

[image: Prior to transition]

[image: After transition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Eventually.

The ng-animate module from Angular seems to be adding...

```
<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";/* more here */
.ng-animate-start{border-spacing:1px 1px;-ms-zoom:1.0001;}/* more here */}</style>
```

...which was adding to the ":before" and ":after" elements from Bootstrap.

I just override the border-spacing for .ng-animate-start in a CSS file to solve it.

[Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/XTWzC/32/)